# Reduction of Meijer G-function

Tags: special-functions

I would like to simplify the following Meijer G-function:

$
G_{1,2}^{1,1}
\left(z\mid \binom{0}{0,a}\right)
$

into a new Meijer G-function of lower order. In other words, I would like to "simplify" the zeros. Is it possible?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha/Mathematica will probably do this (if it is possible at all).  I believe that Mathematica represents functions internally as Meijer G-functions as far as possible.  See http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/MeijerG/ for syntax etc.

Answer (score 7):

This Meijer G-function can be written in terms of the exponential integral $E_n(z)=\int _1^{\infty }t^{-n} e^{-tz}\,dt$ by means of the identity
$$G_{1,2}^{1,1}
\left(-z\mid \binom{0}{0,-a}\right)=e^{z} \left(z^a-\frac{E_{a+1}(z)}{\Gamma (a)}\right).$$